# Flux<List<?> or Flux<?> in spring webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Here is the scenario

a)Tablet use http GET to get users info from another system

b)the other system can add/delete/update users info also and the operations result should show in tablet in time.

To resolve that I use reactor+sse as demo code shows below

In controller

```
@GetMapping 
public Flux<List<User>> listUser() {
    return service.listUser();
}
```

In service

```
public Flux<List<User>> listUser() {
    Flux<List<User>> flux = Flux.generate(
            () -> 0,
            (state, sink) -> {
                synchronized(users) {
                    users.wait();//other thread will notify with all users info is send to service
                }
                sink.next(users);
                newData = false;
                return state + 1;
            });
    return flux;
}
```

My questions are,

a)should I use Flux<User> to instead of Flux<List<User>>? I didn't see any usage of Flux<List<T>> so far. also one advantage is that with Flux<User>, I don't need to push all users info to the tablet, only the add/delete/update ones.

b)if I use Flux<List<User>, what should I write for bodyToFlux's parameters in below code

```
webClient.get()
         .uri("/user")
         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToFlux() //???
```

Comment: it's not clear from your question how do you intend to signal deleted/added users when streaming users to the client

Comment: @BrianClozel with an expansion of User, such as add an enum field "status" or create a new class such as UserXXX which includes two fields, one for class User, one for status